# Adding new dependencies in maven project

Tags: maven

I'm new to maven projects, I'm creating a maven project in eclipse, after that I modified the code to add some spring functionality, now how can I add a spring dependency into my pom.xml. Is there an eclipse plug-in available to resolve the dependencies ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use M2E plugin(you can use plugin  [here](http://download.eclipse.org/technology/m2e/releases) ). once installed, right click on the project-> select Maven -> add dependency -> on the search tab you can type dependency you want for example say springframework , will list all the spring related dependencies. And you can select the dependencies you want. It has some nice ui for pom.xml editing as well.